# Facebook Graph V2.1 How to Filter News Feed or /home without FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

FQL is being deprecated and I use it a lot to query for filtering news feed.

How am I supposed to covert this to Graph API calls?

"SELECT {columns} FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND type=XXX AND app_id=XXXX"

I tried the following:

/v2.1/me/home?filter=application(XXXXX)

I don't get it.. If I use:

/v2.1/me/home?filter=app_XXXX

The result is very inconsistent and how am I suppose to translate source_id=me() ?? 
The filter app_XXX is not even documented anywhere on FB..

On this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/home/

The documentation said that modifiers filter "Retrieve only posts that match a particular stream filter. " Valid filters to be used here can be retrieved using the FQL stream_filter table. Isn't FQL is being deprecated??? or how are we suppose to use stream filters in the graph?

Full of questions pardon me.

Hoping for someone to give me answers or clues...

Comment: You will not be able to use read_stream permission after 4/30/2015 anyway. So does it really matter?

Comment: Yes you still can. Your app need to pass the Facebook Review. can you give me the link to the page which states that is not allowed anymore?  Permissions in 2.1 "read_stream" its still here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1

Comment: Read the requirements to get the permission

Comment: I have updated my comment this page says https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1  we can still use read_stream

Comment: Yes if your replicating the Facebook app on a platform that doesn't have a Facebook app yet

Comment: I think thats just the recommended common usage by facebook. If I created an app other than that purpose is it not allowed?

Comment: We are working on updating the language to make it clear

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your profile here in stackoverflow. Thank you for clarifying this. I Really appreciate it. For now I will use the FQL until then I hope it is still supported and possible to do things just like in FQL.

Comment: Using FQL or not will not matter. You would still need read_stream I assume? Even if your app was created before 4/30/2014 you need to get that permission approved by 4/30/2015

Comment: the app is create before 4/30/2014. It's ok to get that permission. It's do or die anyway.

Comment: You can use it until 4/30/2015 so if you want to have an app that works for a few months you can use it

Comment: The app is created way back 2012 and its working fine everyday i'm just trying to upgrade to the latest graph version as soon as i can. 8 months to go.. hopefully the updated graph language is way better and comes early.

Comment: There are nothing that will come so you can use read_stream after 4/30/2015

Comment: There should be a big sign post that "read_stream" is being deprecated as of now there is nothing.